# Prove that the upper bound, supremum, infimum and lower bound of the set $A=\{7+\frac{9}{5x}~|~ x ≥2\}$ exist or do not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

So far, I think that $\inf(A) = 7$ and that there is no supremum. I'm just not too sure how to prove this.

Comment: You are correct, the infimum is 7 and the supremum will be the lowest upper bound, which is 7.9

Comment: Thank you. So that means I can say that max(A) = sup(A) = 7.9, correct?

Comment: Yes, you surely can in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must realise that any monotonically decreasing sequence has a lower bound, from the Monotone Convergence Theorem. Hence, a lower bound will surely exist. Now, you can show by induction that 7 will be a lower bound, and the greatest one at that (Take any $M \gt 7$, and see what happens to your induction hypothesis)